# String to long in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing this store procedure, but keep getting error.

My procedure:

```
USE AllCtuStudentInfo
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectProcedure4

    @myVar VARCHAR(8000),
    @Schema varchar(50),
    @ID int
    --@ix INT = 1


AS
--WHILE @ix < 1000
BEGIN
    set @myVar = 'SELECT '+@Schema+'.Student.Name, '+@Schema+'.Student.Surname, '+@Schema+'.Course.Name AS Course,'+@Schema+'.LearningUnit.Name AS [Learning Unit], '+@Schema+'.Formative.[Formative Name], '+@Schema+'.FormativeMark.Mark, '+@Schema+'.Summative.[Summative Name], '+@Schema+'.SummativeMark.Mark AS Mark FROM '+@Schema+'.LearningUnit INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.Formative INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.Course INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.SummativeMark INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.FormativeMark INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.Student ON '+@Schema+'.FormativeMark.FK_Student = '+@Schema+'.Student.ID ON '+@Schema+'.SummativeMark.FK_Student = '+@Schema+'.Student.ID ON  '+@Schema+'.Course.ID = '+@Schema+'.Student.FK_Course  INNER JOIN '+@Schema+'.Summative ON '+@Schema+'.SummativeMark.FK_Summative = '+@Schema+'.Summative.ID ON '+@Schema+'.Formative.ID = '+@Schema+'.FormativeMark.FK_Formative ON  '+@Schema+'.LearningUnit.ID = '+@Schema+'.Summative.FK_LU AND '+@Schema+'.LearningUnit.ID = '+@Schema+'.Formative.FK_LU WHERE '+@Schema+'.Student.ID = '''+CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10))+''';'
    --SET @ix = @ix + 1
    EXEC @myVar
END
```

How I execute it:

```
USE AllCtuStudentInfo

EXEC SelectProcedure4 @myVar = '',  @Schema = 'Auckland_Park', @ID = 1
```

The error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SelectProcedure4, Line 15
>
> The name 'SELECT Auckland_Park.Student.Name,
>   Auckland_Park.Student.Surname, Auckland_Park.Course.Name AS
>   Course,Auckland_Park.LearningUnit.Name AS [Learning Unit],
>   Auckland_Park.Formative.[Formative Name],
>   Auckland_Park.FormativeMark.Mark, Auckland_Park.Summative.[Summative
>   Name], Auckland_Park.SummativeMark.Mark AS Mark FROM
>   Auckland_Park.LearningUnit INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.Formative INNER
>   JOIN Auckland_Park.Course INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.SummativeMark INNER
>   JOIN Auckland_Park.FormativeMark INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.Student ON
>   Auckland_Park.FormativeMark.FK_Student = Auckland_Park.Student.ID ON
>   Auckland_Park.SummativeMark.FK_Student = Auckland' is not a valid
>   identifier.

As you can see it gets cut off. I tried a few other methods, but I always end up with the same error and it gets cut off at the same spot.

Please help!

Comment: Try `exec (SelectProcedure4  '','Auckland_Park',1)`

Comment: The *error message* is truncated, not the underlying string (select @myvar would be correct) - as said you need to call EXEC (@myVar) with parentheses.

Comment: Without the parenthesis, `EXEC` assumes you are executing a stored procedure, not a query; SQL Server thinks the query is a proc name.  I suggest you use sp_executesql instead of EXEC, and parameterize the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example that uses sp_executesql along with a parameterized query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectProcedure4

    @myVar nvarchar(MAX),
    @Schema sysname,
    @ID int
AS
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(130) = QUOTENAME(@Schema);

SET @myVar = 'SELECT '+@SchemaName+'.Student.Name, '+@SchemaName+'.Student.Surname, '+@SchemaName+'.Course.Name AS Course,'+@SchemaName+'.LearningUnit.Name AS [Learning Unit], '+@SchemaName+'.Formative.[Formative Name], '+@SchemaName+'.FormativeMark.Mark, '+@SchemaName+'.Summative.[Summative Name], '+@SchemaName+'.SummativeMark.Mark AS Mark FROM '+@SchemaName+'.LearningUnit INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.Formative INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.Course INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.SummativeMark INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.FormativeMark INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.Student ON '+@SchemaName+'.FormativeMark.FK_Student = '+@SchemaName+'.Student.ID ON '+@SchemaName+'.SummativeMark.FK_Student = '+@SchemaName+'.Student.ID ON  '+@SchemaName+'.Course.ID = '+@SchemaName+'.Student.FK_Course  INNER JOIN '+@SchemaName+'.Summative ON '+@SchemaName+'.SummativeMark.FK_Summative = '+@SchemaName+'.Summative.ID ON '+@SchemaName+'.Formative.ID = '+@SchemaName+'.FormativeMark.FK_Formative ON  '+@SchemaName+'.LearningUnit.ID = '+@SchemaName+'.Summative.FK_LU AND '+@SchemaName+'.LearningUnit.ID = '+@SchemaName+'.Formative.FK_LU WHERE '+@SchemaName+'.Student.ID = @ID;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @myVar, N'@ID int', @ID= @ID;
GO
```

Comment: The only change I would make would be to wrap SchemaName inside QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection. Since it is sysname the length is fairly short but you can still do some pretty nasty stuff in a short string.

Comment: @SeanLange, SchemaName in the script is the value returned by QUOTENAME from the original parameter.  Doesn't that address the SQL injection concern?

Comment: @DanGuzman yes it does. I missed that when I read it originally. Even so you already had my +1. :)